# What is the criteria to differentiate 'feature' and 'requirement' in software engineering?

Tags: requirements

I am now using a tool named Jama(It is not a java-based mathematical package. It has the same name, but totally different from that one.), which is used to manage configuration of features and requirements. There is a function to define and make relationships between each feature and requirement, But I can't use it well because I cannot understand these concepts.

I googled for a while and found this. From this page. 
[enter link description here](http://pmblog.accompa.com/2009/07/13/features-vs-requirements-requirements-management-basics/)

> A requirement is something the product must do or a quality it must have.

And also found this sentence too.

> A feature is a set of related requirements that allows the user to satisfy a business objective or need.

My questions are these.

1. Is the relationship between features and requirements is 1:N? Or can one requirement have relationship with 2 or more features?
2. Is feature only a set of requirements & relationships? Is there any difference of the level of abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no strict definitions of these terms which are generally accepted in the software industry. So this is my opinion.

A feature is a subset of functionality, used in descriptions of the system. A requirement is a work order for an engineer who constructs some part of the system.

So in my opinion they are not different levels of abstraction as much as they belong to different realms. You may start a requirement analysis with a list of proposed features, but once the analysis is complete you have a set of (specific, testable, etc) requirements which is what you use to construct the system.

Once the system is built, you can throw away the requirements but the features are used in sales material. I think Shrivathsan's (derived) definitions are too narrow (I wouldn't throw business or customer needs in there), but the example is pretty good.

As to one-to-one or one-to-many, one requirement can absolutely support multiple features and obviously one feature will give rise to several requirements, so the relationship would be many-to-many.